# MySql not inserting

Tags: php, mysql, sql

Is not giving me any error, I am already linked with server but I am still unable to get it work.

It's still unable to add message, do you see any errors?

```
function pridaj_tovar() {

    if ($link = spoj_s_db()) {    
    $sql = "INSERT INTO `Auto-Moto`".
            "(`Tovar`, `Kategoria`,`Mesto`, `Cena`, `ID`, `Popis`)".
            "VALUES".
            "('$_POST['nazov']', '$_POST['kategorie']', '$_POST['mesta']',' $_POST['cena']', NULL,'$_POST['popis']')";
        $result = mysql_query($sql, $link); 
        if ($result) {
            // unable to add
        echo '<p>inserting was successful.</p>'. "\n"; 
    } else {
            // unable to add!
        echo '<p class="chyba">Nastala chyba pri pridávaní tovaru.</p>' . "\n";  
    }
        mysql_close($link);
    } else {
        // NEpodarilo sa spojiť s databázovým serverom!
        echo '<p class="chyba">NEpodarilo sa spojiť s databázovým serverom!</p>';
    }
  }
```

Comment: The problem is that you have no error handler.

Comment: `if ($link = spoj_s_db())...` <- ??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is how you should handle field  and table names with spaces,dashes (etc) :

```
  $sql = "INSERT INTO `Auto-Moto`".
   "(`Tovar`, `Kategoria`,`Mesto`, `Cena`, `ID`, `Popis`)".
   "VALUES".
   "('Something', 'Something1', 'word', '50', NULL, 'anotherword')";

  $sql = "INSERT INTO `Auto-Moto`". 
         "(`Tovar`, `Kategoria`,`Mesto`, `Cena`, `ID`, `Popis`)". 
         "VALUES". " 
         ('{$_POST['nazov']}', '{$_POST['kategorie']}', '{$_POST['mesta']}','{$_POST['cena']}',  
  NULL,'{$_POST['popis']}')";
```

Comment: and if i want to do something like this ?
  $sql = "INSERT INTO `Auto-Moto`".
   "(`Tovar`, `Kategoria`,`Mesto`, `Cena`, `ID`, `Popis`)".
   "VALUES".
   "('$_POST['nazov']', '$_POST['kategorie']', '$_POST['mesta']',' $_POST['cena']', NULL,'$_POST['popis']')";

Comment: Does this site have buy a beer button?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to see an error message change this line:

```
$result = mysql_query($sql, $link);
```

To this:

```
$result = mysql_query($sql, $link) or die ("Error in query: $query. " . mysql_error());
```

But you should really learn to use `mysqli_*` extensions since `mysql_*` extensions—such as what you are using—will be depreciated in PHP 5.5.  So change that to this:

```
$result = mysqli_query($sql, $link) or die ("Error in query: $query. " . mysqli_error());
```

And be sure to change any other `mysqli_*` extensions you code might have in place, such as in the `spoj_s_db()` function you are calling as the `$link` for a DB connection.

Additionally, your `$sql` has a few formatting errors.  Try this instead:

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO Auto-Moto"
     . " (Tovar, Kategoria, Mesto, Cena, ID, Popis)"
     . " VALUES"
     . " ('Something', 'Something1', 'word', '50', NULL, 'anotherword')"
     ;
```

Note the spaces in the query around the `. "` concatenation strings.  In your original query the formatting had no spaces at all. Which would cause MySQL to choke on the query.

Answer (score 0):

You have several problems in your way of making query.

Firstly, your table name is quite non standard (Auto-Moto) so you might need to add quotes around it.
Secondly, it is always a good practice to add some space on proper locations so you could change:

```
"VALUES"
```

with 
       " VALUES "

But you need to provide which error you have received and your table structure.

Answer (score 0):

You missed a lot of space in your Query :

Copy this :

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO Auto-Moto ".
       "(Tovar, Kategoria, Mesto, Cena, ID, Popis) ".
       "VALUES ".
       "('Something', 'Something1', 'word', '50', NULL, 'anotherword')";
```